# Binding not working properly in treeview WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I have an `Employee` Class as shown below:

```
public class Employee : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public Employee()
        {
            _subEmployee = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<Employee> SubEmployee
        {
            get { return _subEmployee; }
            set
            {
                _subEmployee = value;
                NotifiyPropertyChanged("SubEmployee");
            }
        }

        ObservableCollection<Employee> _subEmployee;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        void NotifiyPropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
```

I am creating a collection of employee class in Main window constructor
and adding it to an observable collection of employee as shown below:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Employee> Emp { get; private set; }
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Emp = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();
            Emp.Add(new Employee(){Name = "Anuj"});
            Emp.Add(new Employee() { Name = "Deepak" });
            Emp.Add(new Employee() { Name = "Aarti" });

            Emp[0].SubEmployee.Add(new Employee(){Name = "Tonu"});
            Emp[0].SubEmployee.Add(new Employee() { Name = "Monu" });
            Emp[0].SubEmployee.Add(new Employee() { Name = "Sonu" });

            Emp[2].SubEmployee.Add(new Employee() { Name = "Harsh" });
            Emp[2].SubEmployee.Add(new Employee() { Name = "Rahul" });
            Emp[2].SubEmployee.Add(new Employee() { Name = "Sachin" });
            this.DataContext = this;
        }      
    }
```

I have set the DataContext as self.
Now, in xaml file I have created a hierarchical template of treeview and binded data as shown below:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding SubEmployee}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Now when I keep, `TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Emp}"` , binding works properly
and I can see the tree view structure after running the code.
However when I keep `TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding}"`, I see no result after running the code.

To my understanding, keeping `ItemSource = "{Binding}"` means I am binding to the evaluated value of the current datacontext.
As my datacontext is set to self, `ItemSource = "{Binding}"` should mean I am binding to the only property of DataContext i.e. Emp and I should get proper result.

Please help me in understanding the problem I am getting in keeping binding as
`ItemSource = "{Binding}"`.

Comment: Why do you think that it should bind to that "single" property of your datacontext? 1. WPF doesn't have any convention that forces it to bind to a single property of control's DataContext. 2. Your `MainWindow ` actually has far more properties than just `Emp`, though they are all inherited from the standard `Window`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> "To my understanding, keeping `ItemSource = "{Binding}"` means I am binding to the evaluated value of the current datacontext."

Correct AND that is the issue. ItemsSource expects the binding source to be of type `IEnumerable` but you are binding to `Window`.

> "...should mean I am binding to the only property of DataContext i.e. Emp and I should get proper result."

No. No such "single property" assumption exists in WPFs binding conventions.

Change...

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

To...

```
this.DataContext = Emp;
```

Or, alternatively, change binding in XAML and specify the correct member on the DataContext to bind to using `Path`...

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Emp}">
```